# Alphabetizing data from the filter function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data from multiple tabs in Google Sheets that I am combining into one master tab. I would then like the data on the master tab to be alphabetized based on the last name in one column automatically if more information is added. Here is the formula I used to combine the multiple tabs onto the master tab:

```
={filter(tab1!A5:Z, tab1!B5:B<>"");FILTER(tab2!A5:Z, tab2!B5:B<>""); FILTER(tab3!A5:Z, tab3!B5:B<>""); FILTER(tab4!A5:Z, tab4!B5:B<>"");FILTER(tab5!A5:Z, tab5!B5:B<>""); FILTER(tab6!A5:Z, tab6!B5:B<>"")}
```

I have not been able to find anything that would work when I google "how to sort data in abc order from a filter function google sheets".

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Reagarding "alphabetizing data" what  you tried to do that? Also add a brief description of your search/search efforts about this as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SORT()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150) and there's even an example in its documentation that applies to your situation:

```
SORT({1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6}, 2, FALSE)
```

So if the last name is in  column B, which is the second column you could write (formatted for clarity)

```
=SORT(
  {
    FILTER(tab1!A5:Z, tab1!B5:B<>"");
    FILTER(tab2!A5:Z, tab2!B5:B<>"");
    FILTER(tab3!A5:Z, tab3!B5:B<>"");
    FILTER(tab4!A5:Z, tab4!B5:B<>"");
    FILTER(tab5!A5:Z, tab5!B5:B<>"");
    FILTER(tab6!A5:Z, tab6!B5:B<>"")
  },
  2,
  TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was needing.

Comment: Glad it helped @Annie! Please consider accepting the answer.